# Mapbox map layer is not finding/coloring France

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have this issue where a Mapbox map with 2 different layers is displaying correctly except for France. The packages I am using are :

```
"@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^4.7.0",
"mapbox-gl": "^1.13.0",
"mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^2.0.1",
```

Here's the declaration of my layers :

```
 const doneCountriesLayer = {
  id: 'done-countries-layer',
  type: 'fill',
  'source-layer': 'ne_10m_admin_0_countries-cdobzp',
  filter: ['match', ['get', 'ISO_A2'], doneCountryCodes, true, false],
  paint: {
   'fill-color': '#00b483',
   'fill-opacity': 0.8,
  },
 };

 const todoCountriesLayer = {
  id: 'todo-countries-layer',
  type: 'fill',
  'source-layer': 'ne_10m_admin_0_countries-cdobzp',
  filter: ['match', ['get', 'ISO_A2'], todoCountryCodes, true, false],
  paint: {
   'fill-color': '#f4c43c',
   'fill-opacity': 0.8,
  },
};
```

So what is going on here is I am creating a layer with a specific set of countries to show up in green for the countries done and yellow for the countries marked as todo. As you can see in the following screen capture of the inspector, the countries done array contains the country code for France (FR).

[image: inspector]

However, once the page renders, the map is showing up like this :

[image]

Is the mapbox country code for France not the "usual" one or is there something I am missing?

Thank you for your help